# mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES) wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

im getting this error when im trying to connect to the database in my wordpress site ?

i set my wp_debug to ture then this message showed up

---

i found some info about this topic but it wasn't like my issue - and i didn't get a satisfying answers

**Erorr**

```
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

---

**In line 1635**

```
in F:\folderlocation**\wp-db.php on line 1635

if ( WP_DEBUG ) {
                mysqli_real_connect( $this->dbh, $host, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, null, $port, $socket, $client_flags );
```

---

**Full Error Alert Message**

```
**Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in F:\folderlocation**\wp-db.php on line 1635**
```

im using

- xampp v3.2.4
- i'm not that good with sql
- server localhost - apache port 80

---

Please if you have any idea how to fix this tell me
or link me to a topic that can help me
but before you link me anything make sure that topic is for wordpress not for any other application
thanks

Error establishing a database connection

Comment: there nothing wrong with th php code , all the database name username and password is correct i doubled checked that and it's correct the issue within something else

Comment: Why is it tagged phpMyAdmin?

Comment: `mysqli` isn't going to tell you that your credentials are wrong if they aren't.

Comment: this is tagged phpmyadmin because i'm using phpmyadmin on xampp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone who replied for snily i found the answer after
when i type an ip address or localhost in the privileges tap it gives this error
for some reason

i just added "" % "" = for all hosts and now it's all seems to work just fine

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing
`define ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');`
with
`define ('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');`
in wp_config.php

Answer (score 0):

If you are on local machine make sure there is no password on this config : (if you have password on MySql, then only use password)

```
/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
```

and if you are on live server, your password is wrong. Also, your MySql host can be wrong. Check the credentials properly on the config file.

Comment: thanks for replying but this also didn't work  now it's showing me Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: please post your wp-config.php configuration and also it's on local machine or server?

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add up my answer as I was able to login before I had issues with logging-in **WordPress** php myadmin. **Just like what is discussed by the OP**

Note: You can find the `wp-config.php` file in this location. This is my location from my windows computer.

`C:\Bitnami\wordpress-5.4.1-0\apps\wordpress\htdocs`

On your `wp-config.php` file you can just take a look of the username and password and log it in.

```
/** MySQL database username */
define( 'DB_USER', 'some_username' );

/** MySQL database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'some_password' );
```

Take note `'some_username'` & `'some_password'` is not the actual value there on your `wp-config.php` file. This is what I entered on the `php myadmin` login page and it worked.